# Is there a built-in PHP function to only return certain array keys with their value?

Tags: php

Given the following array:

```php
$data = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
];
```

Is there a PHP function that, called this way:

```php
x($data, ['a', 'c']);
```

Would return this result:

```php
[
    'a' => 1,
    'c' => 3
]
```

Please note that *I know how to write the code to generate the expected result*, so **please only answer if there is a native PHP function to do that**, or alternatively to mention that there isn't, if you know this for a fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in function that does the exact same thing, but you can easily combine two of them to achieve what you want:

```
$keys = ['a', 'c'];
$result = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keys));
```

[`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) flips the values and keys of a given array — this is done to transform your search values into keys of an array. [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) compares the keys of the two arrays and returns the matches.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/118142)